# Send variable in LParam in VBA for Excel

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, mfc

I'm attempting to send a message from VBA to a c++ application. What I have below works, in that the message is getting sent to my message map (Yay!).  However, I'm not able to pass any data along.  I've tried a few different approaches, as seen in my code, but none of them seem to be getting that LPARAM across.

Any help would be appreciated!

VBA:

```
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
 ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Const WM_APP = &H803C&

Sub Test()
    Call SetPartNumber(123)
End Sub

Sub SetPartNumber(partNumber As Double)
    Dim result As Long, hwnd As Long

    partNumber2 = VarPtr(partNumber)
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Data Collector")

    result = PostMessage(hwnd, WM_APP, 0, partNumber2) ' attempt using a var pointer
    result = PostMessage(hwnd, WM_APP, 0, partNumber) ' attempt using just the variable
End Sub
```

My c++ Data Collector:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCellDlg, CDialogEx)
  ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP + 60, PleasePleaseWork)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT CCellDlg::PleasePleaseWork(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  double partNumber = LOWORD(lParam);
  double partNumber1 = HIWORD(lParam);
  double partNumber2 = wParam;
  double partNumber3 = lParam;

  AfxMessageBox("Yay!");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pointers are valid in the process where they originate only, so passing `VarPtr` across process boundaries is meaningless. Passing a `Double` value could work, if you are sending from a 64-bit process to another 64-bit process. Taking the lower or upper half of a double is meaningless still: That's not how floating point values are encoded.

Comment: WM_COPYDATA is probably a better choice as the OS will take care of copyng across the boundary for you.

Comment: I was worried about sending a memory address across different processes, and what you say makes sense... even more so when I realized I was clearing the memory right away using PostMessage instead of SendMessage.  WM_COPYDATA paired with SendMessage seemed to do the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the suggestion in the comment above, I switched to using WM_COPYDATA.  I am now able to send a message to another application, as well as being able to transfer data. Thanks all!

VBA

```
Type COPYDATASTRUCT
    dwData As Long
    cbData As Long
    lpData As Long
End Type

Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const WM_COPYDATA = &H4A&

Sub Test()
    Call SetPartNumber("123456")
End Sub

Sub SetPartNumber(partNumber As String)
    Dim result As Long, hwnd As Long

    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Data Collector")

    If hwnd <> 0 Then
        Dim cds As COPYDATASTRUCT

        cds.dwData = 0
        cds.cbData = Len(partNumber) * 2 + 2
        cds.lpData = StrPtr(partNumber)

        result = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, cds)
    End If
End Sub
```

c++

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCell7Dlg, CDialogEx)
  ON_WM_COPYDATA()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CCell7Dlg::OnCopyData(CWnd* pWnd, COPYDATASTRUCT* pCopyDataStruct)
{
  // Gathering the data this way did not work for my c++ project
  // CString recievedText = (LPCSTR)(pCopyDataStruct->lpData);

  // I have to piece the data together like this instead
  char* recievedText = (char*) pCopyDataStruct->lpData;

  double size = pCopyDataStruct->cbData;

  string gatheredText;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      gatheredText+= recievedText;

    *recievedText++;
  }
  return CDialogEx::OnCopyData(pWnd, pCopyDataStruct);
}
```