# How to send WM_COPYDATA to Total Commander in VBA 64bit?

Tags: vba, wm-copydata, total-commander

I am trying send `WM_COPYDATA` to Totoal Commander (TC) using VBA.
Here is what I've done so far.
And there is no error message.

## What I've checked

1. The setting in `TC` is correct because I can call TC's internal commands  using `sendmessage` in Autohotkey.
2. For `result = SendMessage(hwndTC, 1075, 4001, 0) 'FocusLeft`  , it works.
   That means  the `hwnd` of Total commander has been correctly got And the message has been correctly sent.
3. The not workable part is the `Sub TC_SetPath(hwndTarget, UserCMD As String)` .
   I've checked some other code and tried to make following change

```vb
cds.cbData = Len(UserCMD) + 1  ' not work
cds.cbData = Len(UserCMD) + 2  ' not work
cds.cbData = (Len(UserCMD) + 1)*2  ' not work
```

4. I've also tried the code here [1](https://dobon.net/vb/bbs/log3-53/31406.html). That is to covert the string input to Byte. Still doesn't work and no error message.

```vb
Sub TC_SetPath(hwndTarget, UserCMD As String)
   Dim cds As CopyDataStruct, result As LongPtr
   Dim MsgBytes() As Byte
   MsgBytes = StrConv(UserCMD, vbUnicode)
   
   cds.dwData = Asc("E") + 256 * Asc("M")  'OK
   
   cds.cbData = UBound(MsgBytes)
   cds.lpData = VarPtr(MsgBytes(1))   'OK
   
   ' Send the WM_COPYDATA message
   result = SendMessage(hwndTarget, WM_COPYDATA, 0, VarPtr(cds))
   If result = 0 Then
       Debug.Print "3"
       Debug.Print GetLastErrorStr(Err.LastDllError) 'The operation completed successfully.
   End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

## 2nd version of VBA code based on the suggetions so far

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
        
Public Type CopyDataStruct
    dwData As LongPtr
    cbData As Long
    lpData As LongPtr
End Type
Private Const WM_COPYDATA = &H4A

Sub test()
    Call TC_SendUserCMD("em_focusfile")
End Sub

Sub TC_SendUserCMD(UserCMD As String)
    Dim cds As CopyDataStruct, result As LongPtr
    Dim hwndTC As LongPtr
    Dim wParam As LongPtr
    wParam = 0
    hwndTC = FindWindow("TTOTAL_CMD", vbNullString)
    
    cds.dwData = Asc("E") + 256 * Asc("M")
    cds.cbData = Len(UserCMD) * 2 + 2
    cds.lpData = StrPtr(UserCMD)
    result = SendMessage(hwndTC, WM_COPYDATA, wParam, cds)
End Sub
```

## This is the 1st version of VBA code.

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As LongPtr

Public Type CopyDataStruct
    dwData As LongPtr
    cbData As LongPtr
    lpData As LongPtr
End Type
Private Const WM_COPYDATA = &H4A
Sub test()
    Dim newPath As String
    ThisFile = "D:\xxx\xxx\.mhtml"
    newPath = ThisFile & "\:\n" & "\0"
    hwndTC = FindWindow("TTOTAL_CMD", vbNullString)
    result = SendMessage(hwndTC, 1075, 4001, 0)  'FocusLeft  OK
    result = SendMessage(hwndTC, 1075, 3001, 0)  'NewTab  OK
    
    Call TC_SetPath(hwndTC, newPath)
End Sub

Sub TC_SetPath(hwndTarget, UserCMD As String)
    Dim cds As CopyDataStruct
    
    cds.dwData = Asc("C") + 256 * Asc("D")  'OK
    ' cds.cbData = (Len(UserCMD) + 1)*2  'also tried, not work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950108/send-variable-in-lparam-in-vba-for-excel
    cds.cbData = Len(UserCMD) + 1  
    cds.lpData = StrPtr(UserCMD)   'OK
    
    ' Send the WM_COPYDATA message
    result = SendMessage(hwndTarget, WM_COPYDATA, 0, cds)
End Sub
```

## Workable Autohotkey Script

And below is the workable Autohotkey script with the same function.

```
F1::
{
    ThisFile:="D:\xxx\xxx.mhtml"

    newPath:=ThisFile . "\:`r" . "\0"
    SendMessage(0x433,4001,0,,"ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD")   ; FocusLeft
    SendMessage(0x433,3001,0,,"ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD")   ; NewTab
    TC_SetPath(newPath)                                 ; CD to DirPath
}
TC_SetPath(userCommand) 
{
    ; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=538463&sid=4471e03917209854441ac07ebdc70901#p538463
    static dwData := 17475  ;Ord("C") +256*Ord("D")
    static WM_COPYDATA := 0x4A
    cbData := Buffer(StrPut(userCommand, 'CP0'))
    StrPut(userCommand, cbData, 'CP0')
    COPYDATASTRUCT := Buffer(A_PtrSize * 3)
    NumPut('Ptr', dwData, 'Ptr', cbData.size, 'Ptr', cbData.ptr, COPYDATASTRUCT)
    MsgResult:=SendMessage( WM_COPYDATA,, COPYDATASTRUCT,, 'ahk_class TTOTAL_CMD')
    return MsgResult
}
```

Comment: What does "it does NOT work" mean? Do you receive an error? If yes, when which line? Please, try running the code line by line and check what each line does. To do that, press `F8` to jump from line to line and when stopped **move the cursor over the variables and see their value**. Is `hwndTC` different than zero? If so, test the following `result` values. If not, this means that `FindWindow` did not return the application window. And specify this in your question (editing it). Asking in this way it is improbable to be helped, except the case when somebody else uses `Total Commander` to test.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to make the question more clear.  I'll revise the orginal post. For `result = SendMessage(hwndTC, 1075, 4001, 0) 'FocusLeft`  , it works. That means  the `hwnd` of Total commander has been correctly got And the message has been correctly sent. The not workable part is the `Sub TC_SetPath(hwndTarget, UserCMD As String)` .

Comment: What are the values of `varptr(cds.cbData) - varptr(cds)` and `varptr(cds.lpData) - varptr(cds)`?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FormatMessage Lib "kernel32" Alias "FormatMessageA" _
        (ByVal dwFlags As Long, lpSource As Any, _
        ByVal dwMessageId As Long, ByVal dwLanguageId As Long, _
        ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long, Arguments As LongPtr) As Long
        
Public Type CopyDataStruct
    dwData As LongPtr
    cbData As LongPtr
    lpData As LongPtr
End Type
Private Const WM_COPYDATA = &H4A

'Error Messages read__________________________________________________
Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = &H100
Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY = &H2000
Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE = &H800
Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING = &H400
Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = &H1000
Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS = &H200
Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK = &HFF
Private Const LANG_USER_DEFAULT = &H400&
'____________________________________________________________________

Sub test()
    Dim newPath As String, ThisFile As String, hwndTC As LongPtr, result As LongPtr
    ThisFile = "C:\Users\wei_x\Desktop\Nepcon2024\0a7722dd-e8a5-4036-9250-19e0932fe2a9.mhtml"
    newPath = ThisFile & "\:\n" & "\0"
    hwndTC = FindWindow("TTOTAL_CMD", vbNullString)
    result = SendMessage(hwndTC, 1075, 4001, 0)  'FocusLeft  OK
    If result = 0 Then
        Debug.Print GetLastErrorStr(Err.LastDllError) 'The operation completed successfully.
    End If
    result = SendMessage(hwndTC, 1075, 3001, 0)  'NewTab  OK
    If result = 0 Then
        Debug.Print GetLastErrorStr(Err.LastDllError) 'The operation completed successfully.
    End If
    Call TC_SetPath(hwndTC, newPath)
End Sub

Function GetLastErrorStr(dwErrCode As Long) As String

  Static sMsgBuf As String * 257, dwLen As Long

  dwLen = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM _
                        Or FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS _
                        Or FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK, _
                        ByVal 0&, _
                        dwErrCode, LANG_USER_DEFAULT, _
                        ByVal sMsgBuf, 256&, CLngPtr(0))

  If dwLen Then
      GetLastErrorStr = Trim$(Left$(sMsgBuf, dwLen))
  Else
     GetLastErrorStr = "Unknown error."
  End If

End Function

Sub TC_SetPath(hwndTarget, UserCMD As String)
    Dim cds As CopyDataStruct, result As LongPtr
    
    cds.dwData = Asc("C") + 256 * Asc("D")  'OK
    cds.cbData = Len(UserCMD) + 1
    cds.lpData = StrPtr(UserCMD)   'OK
    
    ' Send the WM_COPYDATA message
    result = SendMessage(hwndTarget, WM_COPYDATA, 0, cds)
    If result = 0 Then
        Debug.Print GetLastErrorStr(Err.LastDllError) 'The operation completed successfully.
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, you can have a confirmation if the API calls work correctly...

Comment: `cbData` is `Long`, `wParam` is `LongPtr`.

Comment: @FaneDuru, Thanks for your kind reply. I've test it. The output is that `The operation completed successfully.`. I tried to change the `dwData` or `cbData` to some other value, but still it says `The operation completed successfully.`. Also, I've tried @GSerg's suggestion. Still no error message got.

Comment: I've test with the worksable ahk script. The return value from Total Commander is awlays 0.  That means with the above VBA code. It can NOT catch the actual error message even there is some.

Comment: Where do you think it does not work? Please, run the code in a small window, line by line and see that it activates the left commander window and creates the new tab...

Comment: Another problem is that `cds.cbData` should be `Len(UserCMD) * 2 + 2`, if you intend to pass `StrPtr(UserCMD)`.

Comment: @GSerg That's correct. I only used his way of `cbData` calculation. I must confess, I did not clearly understand what he tries doing...

Comment: As for `cbData` , I've tested serveral ones, as you can see in the main post, none of them work.  The reason I use ` Len(UserCMD)+1`  is just to keep it the same as that in Autohotkey, which has proved to work.

Comment: @FaneDuru Appreciate your explanation with patience. I've reviesd my orginal post, where you can see that, I've tried the method you and GSerg provided, the workable and non-workable part is identified.

Comment: I posted the 2nd edition based on your ideas.  I removed the get_error_message part (with great appreciation to FaneDuru and I've learned it) to make the code concise. As you can see, it is just used to send user defined command to TC. There is no program error and also no operation executed by TC.

Comment: @Valuex But, I installed a trial version of Commander and, as I tried suggesting, the code changes the activation to the left window/pane and also creates a new tab. Didn't it do it in your installation? Did you select the right pane and running the code line by line don't you see it working as I tried explaining that it is happening in my installation?

Comment: @FaneDuru, `activation to the left window/pane and also creates a new tab`, this is the workable part in the 1st version. The non-workable part is the `TC_SetPath(UserCMD As String)`.  Thanks for your great support to install TC for the test!  If you 1)create a `usercmd.ini` file under folder of `Total Commander`, (where TotalCMD64.exe is), and 2) append something like this `[em_focusfile]`  `cmd=CD` `param=D:\SoftX\AHK_Scripts_V2\Lib\ `   . This is to navigate to a new folder. 3) then call  `TC_SendUserCMD("em_focusfile")`  , you'll see that the function doesn't work  and no error message.

Comment: @Valuex No error means that `SendMessage` **really sent the message**.  I mean, all the function call parameters are OK. I think, you have to dig in the direction of **what information and how to send the one you need sending**... It is as I sent a mail to you writing "Open the door, please". But the door is already open and I wanted to transmit "shut down your PC"... Where in Total Commander documentation the necessary command lines to be sent?

Comment: Sorry for late replay. There is no well-documented information about WM_COPYDATA in Total Commander. Except for the AHK version I posted to send the user command, also there is a C++ version : https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=105246#105246

Comment: Also, In the `history.txt` which locates in the directory of main program of Total Commander, there is some description of WM_COPYDATA. Just some description, mainly for `dwData`, no details for the requirement of  `cbData` and `lpData`.